# FxCop: CA1709: Use acronym dictionary like in Resharper

Tags: c#, coding-style, naming-conventions, fxcop

is there a way to circumvent the FxCop's "pascal acronym naming convention" (which is .. controversial) enforcment in rule ca1709 by using an 'acronym dictionary'?

Also, I'm still waiting for a good explaination why this convention is necessary in the first place .. better than just "its convention"? There IS a difference between IS and Is .. also between Gnu and GNU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can be suppressed: see [How to: Customize the Code Analysis Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I was not able to find this complete CustomCodeAnalysis.xml syntax - that is, only examples using the <words> definitions for CA1704.